# Injective function: example of injective function that is not surjective.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Does there exist an injective function that is not surjective? Could I have an example, please?

Comment: What is the definition of surjective according to you?

Comment: @imranfat The function $\operatorname{f} : U \to V$ is surjective if for each $v \in V$, there exists a $u\in U$ for which $\operatorname{f}(u)=v$. This is a *standard* definition.

Comment: In future, you should give us more background on what you know and what you have thought about / tried before just asking for an answer.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991894/finding-a-function-that-is-surjective-but-not-injective

Comment: An injective function should always be considered as not surjective. Otherwise the function would be called a bijection. In other words, by calling something an injective function you are stating that it is not surjective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many examples. It just all depends on how your define the range and domain.

For example $\operatorname{f} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\operatorname{f}(x)=x^3$ is both injective and surjective. But then I can change the image and say that $\operatorname{f} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is given by $\operatorname{f}(x) = x^3$. Now it is still injective but fails to be surjective.

Similarily, the function $\operatorname{g} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\operatorname{g}(x)=x^2$ is neither surjective nor injective. But if I change the range and domain to $\operatorname{g}: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ then it is both injective and surjective.

**Edit:** As requested by the OP:

An example of an injective function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is not surjective is $\operatorname{h}(x)=\operatorname{e}^x$. This "hits" all of the positive reals, but misses zero and all of the negative reals. But the *key point* is the the definitions of injective and surjective depend almost completely on the choice of range and domain.

Comment: Thank you for example $\operatorname{f} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$. And an example of injective function $\operatorname{f} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is not surjective?

Comment: @Mark See above.

Comment: Take any bijective function $f:A \to B$ and then make $B$ "bigger".

Comment: When we change the image to $ \mathbb{C} $  in the first example, how should we constrain it to make it surjective?

Answer (score 3):

How about $f(x)=e^x.$ Your job is to figure out the domain and range. In general, you may want to use the fact that strictly monotone functions are injective.

Comment: Surjective means that every "B" has at least one matching "A" So B is range and A is domain. Why isn't the e-power function surjective then?

Comment: @imranfat It depends completely on the range and domain. Without those, the words "surjective" and "injective" have no meaning.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I like the one-to-one idea much more. We use it with inverses and transcendental functions in Calc. I learned about terms like surjective, injective and bijective so long ago, it seems like these terms aren't so popular anymore

Comment: Yes, surjective is kind of weird like that. But in questions that come up, usually there are two spaces we start with then we want to see if a function from one to the other is surjective, and it may not be easy. Every function is surjective onto its image but this does not help with many problems.